# Role Based Authentication on Restful endpoints in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jwt, jax-rs, restful-authentication

I'm trying to implement some sort of Role Based authentication. I'm using JWT tokens. I've been looking at guides but all of them mention the use of "Spring boot". How would I setup Role Based authentication on my restful endpoint in Java? Preferably through some sort of filter.

I'm looking for a way to simply add: `@Role(Role.ADMIN)` before an endpoint.

I've got the following classes already setup:

- Enum Role:

  ```
  public enum Role {
      User,
      Admin
  }
  ```
- Simple JWT token:

  ```
  {
   "sub": "users/TzMUocMF4p",
   "exp": 1554646441,
   "username": "username@gmail.com",
   "ID": 6,
   "Role": "Admin",
   "iat": 1554641041
  }
  ```
- Simple CRUD endpoint

  ```
  @Path("User")
  public class UserResource {

     @EJB
     private UserDAO userappDAO;


     @GET
     @JWTTokenNeeded
     @Produces("application/json")
     public List<Userapp> all() {
         return userappDAO.getAll();
     }
  }
  ```
- JWT validating (`@JWTTokenNeeded`) class below:

  ```
  @javax.ws.rs.NameBinding
  @Retention(RUNTIME)
  @Target({TYPE, METHOD})
  public @interface JWTTokenNeeded {
  }
  ```

  The actual filter:

  ```
  @Provider
  @JWTTokenNeeded
  @Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
  public class JWTTokenNeededFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {


      @Override
      public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

  // Get the HTTP Authorization header from the request
  String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

  try {
      // Extract the token from the HTTP Authorization header
      String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();
      // Validate the token
      Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("MYSECRET".getBytes("UTF-8")).parseClaimsJws(token);

  }
  catch (Exception e) {
      requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
  }
  }
  }
  ```

If the user isn't authorized I'd like to exit with:
`requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());`

If the user IS authorized the endpoint has to do it's thing.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is implementing an ```@Interceptor``` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853221/what-are-interceptors-in-java-ee

Comment: Have a look at MicroProfile JWT (https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/september/article2.php). With this you get a `java.security.Principal` parsed from the JWT token and can use `@RolesAllowed` on your JAX-RS endpoints. For more information, have a look at the following post: https://rieckpil.de/howto-microprofile-jwt-authentication-with-keycloak-and-react/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a working solution. It includes adding a few lines to the `@JWTTokenNeeded` interface and the `JWTTokenNeededFilter` class.

I ended up with the following code:

JWTTokenNeededFilter:

```
@Provider
@JWTTokenNeeded
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class JWTTokenNeededFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        // Get the HTTP Authorization header from the request
        String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        try {
            // Extract the token from the HTTP Authorization header
            String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();
            // Validate the token
            Claims claims =  Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("MYSECRET".getBytes("UTF-8")).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();

            Method method =resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
            if( method != null){
                // Get allowed permission on method
                JWTTokenNeeded JWTContext = method.getAnnotation(JWTTokenNeeded.class);
                Role permission =  JWTContext.Permissions();

                if(permission != Role.NoRights ) {
                    // Get Role from jwt
                    String roles = claims.get("Role", String.class);
                    Role roleUser = Role.valueOf(roles);

                    // if role allowed != role jwt -> UNAUTHORIZED
                    if (!permission.equals(roleUser)) {
                        throw new Exception("no roles");
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        }
    }
}
```

@JWTTokenNeeded Interface:

```
@javax.ws.rs.NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface JWTTokenNeeded {
    Role Permissions() default Role.NoRights;
}
```

Allowing a Role to access an endpoint is as easy as adding `@JWTTokenNeeded(Permissions = Role.Admin)`

This is an example:

```
@Path("User")
public class UserResource {
    @EJB
    private UserappDAO userDAO;


    @GET
    @JWTTokenNeeded(Permissions = Role.Admin)
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<Userapp> all() {
        return userDAO.getAll();
    }
}
```